# can't install react-native modules

Tags: react-native, npm

I tried to install react-native modules using npm but it gave me an error.
Here is a pic of command line :

[I updated npm but it failed. look at the pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUHHD.jpg)

Comment: Just read the errors. Your node version seems is outdated. You should update node and then retry